# Solving symbolically a trascendental equation containing an exponential

Tags: equation-solving, approximation

Is it possible to solve symbolically this equation for $x$: $$\exp \left(-x^2\right)=\frac{c_1}{\sqrt{c_2-c_3 x}}$$

```
Exp[-x^2] == c1/Sqrt[c2 - c3 x]
```

$c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ are positive constants, with $\frac{c_1}{\sqrt{c_2}}<1$. I am interested in the negative solution, $x<0$. A typical plot of the two functions at the RHS and LHS of the equation is
[image: plot of the two sides of the equation]

I tried an expansion at zero to the second order of the two sides of the equation, but the result besides being complicated does not seem to give a good approximation of the result. On the other side, it is easy to find a numerical solution to the problem:

```
NSolve[Exp[-x^2] == c1/Sqrt[c2 - c3 x] && x < 0, x]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just expand left and right hand sides to the second order and Solve.

Comment: @umby It's preferable that you paste the equation as `code`, not as LaTeX. LaTex is difficult to copy into Mathematica.

Comment: Just start with c1=1,c2=2,c3=3.  Next plot right and left side of equation.  They intersect at about x=-1 and x=1/4.  Use the negative value in FindRoot[Exp[-x^2]==1/(Sqrt[1-2 x]},{x,-1}] to get the negative solution.

Comment: @rhermans, you're right, I will edit my post.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I think you were too hasty doing that. While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that users should test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq) and **wait 24 hours after answers stop arriving before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. That allows people in all timezones to answer your question and an opportunity for other users to point out alternatives, caveats or limitations of the available answers.

Comment: @DanielHuber I think the OP is expecting a closed-form expression where $x$ has been isolated of the style `x == f(c1,c2,c3)` and not `x == f(c1,c2,c3,x)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you have a [Transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), so you will need to approximate, and that implies choices:

- Wich kind of approximation
- To which order
- Around what value?

In this example `PadeApproximant`, order `{1,2}`, around zero.

```
Block[
    {
        eqn = (Exp[-x^2]==c1/Sqrt[c2-c3 x]),    (* Define equality *)
        lhs, rhs, pa
    },
    {lhs,rhs}=List@@ApplySides[Power[#,2]&,eqn];(* Manipulate as necesary *)
    pa=PadeApproximant[lhs, {x, 0, {1,2}}];     (* Algebraic aprox*)
    x/.FullSimplify@Solve[pa == rhs, x]         (* Solve *)
]
```

[image]

How good was the [`PadeApproximant`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadeApproximant.html)? I approximated around zero, you may want to try something else.

[image]

If you are willing to tolerate a messier expression, a better approximation could be around `(c2- 4*c1^2)/c3`, ie  `Solve[rhs==1/4,x]`

```
PadeApproximant[lhs, {x, (c2- 4*c1^2)/c3, {1,2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: This does not match the root for x<0 which is `x -> -0.875079` when using `{c1 -> 1, c2 -> 2, c3 -> 3}` ?  Your gives `-1.78078` for these c values.

Comment: When using approximation at -1, now your method gives good agreement. `-0.874565`  But it also gives second one `-0.216816`, which does not show in the plot as being a root?

Comment: i.e. `Plot[{Exp[-x^2], c1/Sqrt[c2 - c3* x]} /. {c1 -> 1, c2 -> 2, 
   c3 -> 3}, {x, -2, 0}]` shows one root at `x->-0.874565` which your method gives correctly when using x=-1 for approximation. But second value it also gives, which not sure what it means.

Comment: Your answer is good. I was just wondering what the second value mean, that is all.

Comment: @Nasser see the second figure, where I plot RHS too for those arbitrary values. It means the LHS and RHS cross in two places.

Comment: @rhermans, thank you, I see that it is probably impossible to get a simple expression. Your approach works quite fine however.